# I want get the 12,11, 9 real root of equation ant then listplot ,but always get the 12 real root

Tags: equation-solving

*for `a<0` get the `12th` real root, for  `a<0.31`  get the `11th` real root , for  `a<0.51`  get the `9th` real root, but I can not.*

```
pp4 = Collect[
  Simplify[(r^4 (3 - 5 r + 2 r^2) - 
      a^2 (1 - 3 r + 2 r^2 + 2 r^3))^2 - (2 a r^2 Sqrt[
      r (-1 + 2 r) (a^2 + (-1 + r) r)])^2], r]

aaa1 = Table[i, {i, -0.5, 0.5, 0.01/10}] // 
  N; W3 = {}; u = {}; u1 = {}; u2 = {}; ux = {}; ux2 = {}; u3 = {}; \
brom = {}; ux4 = {}; up4 = {}; rm = {}; up = {}; For[i = 1, 
 i <= Length[aaa1],
 u = NSolve[pp4 == 0 /. {a -> aaa1[[i]]}, r]; 
 Piecewise[{{{u1 = u[[12]][[1]], 
     u2 = AppendTo[u2, {aaa1[[i]], u1[[2]]}]}, 
    aaa1[[i]] < 0}, {{ux = u[[11]][[1]], 
     ux2 = AppendTo[ux2, {aaa1[[i]], ux[[2]]}]}}, 
   aaa1[[i]] < 0.31}, {{ux4 = u[[9]][[1]], 
    up4 = AppendTo[up4, {aaa1[[i]], ux4[[2]]}]}, aaa1[[i]] < 0.49}]; 
 up = Join[u2, ux2, up4];
 W3 = AppendTo[W3, {aaa1[[i]], up[[i]][[2]]}];
 i++];

ListPlot[W3]
```

Comment: Please take the time to format the code in your question. While you are at it, perhaps you could also clarify what you are after here. I'm not sure that I understand your question.

Comment: I want get the 12th,11th, 9th  real root of equation

Comment: I get 12 **real** roots for real `a` only for `a == 0`; otherwise, I get only 8 or 6.  So I don't know what you mean by the "12th real root" etc.  Do you mean just the 12th root returned by `NSolve[]`?

Comment: thank you help , i  get the answer  from  @Simon woods,  i mean the the 12th  root for a<0, the 11th root  for a<0.31, the 9th root  for a<0.5.

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you want?

```
rootnumber[a_] := Piecewise[{{12, a < 0}, {11, a < 0.31}, {9, True}}]

roots = r /. Table[NSolve[pp4, r][[rootnumber@a]], {a, -0.5, 0.5, 0.1}]

(* {2.07051, 1.96813, 1.86096, 1.7481, 1.62833, 1.5, 1.36071, 
  1.20694, 1.0335, 0.833689, 0.572604} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much,  your code is what  I  want ,   use your code, I  change  a little ,i get  my answerpp4 = Collect[Simplify[(r^4 (3 - 5 r + 2 r^2) - 
  a^2 (1 - 3 r + 2 r^2 + 2 r^3))^2 - (2 a r^2 Sqrt[
  r (-1 + 2 r) (a^2 + (-1 + r) r)])^2], r];

Comment: pp4 = Collect[
  Simplify[(r^4 (3 - 5 r + 2 r^2) - 
       a^2 (1 - 3 r + 2 r^2 + 2 r^3))^2 - (2 a r^2 Sqrt[
        r (-1 + 2 r) (a^2 + (-1 + r) r)])^2], r]
rootnumber[a_] := Piecewise[{{12, a < 0}, {11, a < 0.31}, {9, True}}]

roots = Table[{a, r /. NSolve[pp4, r][[rootnumber@a]]}, {a, -0.5, 0.5,
    0.01}];ListPlot[roots]

Comment: but what is the problem of my code

Answer (score 2):

To find the roots of pp4

```
pp4 = Collect[Simplify[(r^4 (3 - 5 r + 2 r^2) - 
  a^2 (1 - 3 r + 2 r^2 + 2 r^3))^2 - (2 a r^2 Sqrt[
  r (-1 + 2 r) (a^2 + (-1 + r) r)])^2], r];
Solve[pp4==0,r]
```

Observe that this always has a real root of 1 (for all a). So if you take any power of pp4 it will still have a real root at 1.

```
Solve[pp4^(1/12) == 0, r]
```

Similarly for the roots of pp4^(1/9) or pp4^(1/11).

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed your code, for what it's worth:

```
aaa1 = Table[i, {i, -0.5, 0.5, 0.01/10}] // 
  N; W3 = {}; u = {}; u1 = {}; u2 = {}; ux = {}; ux2 = {}; u3 = {}; \
brom = {}; ux4 = {}; up4 = {}; rm = {}; up = {}; For[i = 1, 
 i <= Length[aaa1], u = NSolve[pp4 == 0 /. {a -> aaa1[[i]]}, r];
 Piecewise[
  Partition[
   Flatten[{{{u1 = u[[12]][[1]], 
       u2 = AppendTo[u2, {aaa1[[i]], u1[[2]]}]}, 
      aaa1[[i]] < 0}, {{ux = u[[11]][[1]], 
       ux2 = AppendTo[ux2, {aaa1[[i]], ux[[2]]}]}}, 
     aaa1[[i]] < 0.31}], 2], 
  Partition[
   Flatten[{{ux4 = u[[9]][[1]], 
      up4 = AppendTo[up4, {aaa1[[i]], ux4[[2]]}]}, aaa1[[i]] < 0.49}],
    2]];
 up = Join[u2, ux2, up4];
 W3 = AppendTo[W3, {aaa1[[i]], up[[i]][[2]]}];
 i++];
ListPlot[W3]
```

[image]

Comment: this is the wrong figure  for 0<a<0.31, this code cannot select the 11th root to the equation pp4=0, for  0.31<a<0.5, this code cannot select the 9th root to the equation pp4=0,

Comment: @bob This is your code, I just made it run properly. It's hard to see at a glance without explanation what you're doing with it.